# Call a class to add tabs in a QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget

I am trying to create tabs each time that i press a button that i added to a toolbar. For this i create a windows in Pyqt, and call the class NewTab, which has the QWidget that i want to add in the QTabWidget.

This is my code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):

    self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
    self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)
    self.setCentraWidget(self.tabWidget)

    self.setLayout(NewTab().newTab.tab_layout)


class NewTab(QWidget):
  list_1 = []            #These lists are for another method that i will use later
  list_2 = []           

  def __init__(self):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.newTab()

  def newTab(self):
    self.new_tab = QWidget()
    Window.tabWidget.addTab(self.new_tab)

    plot = MatPlotLibFigure()                  #This is another class that i add 
                                               #in the splitter as a widget

    self.splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
    self.splitter.addWidget(plot)

    self.splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.splitter2.addWidget(self.splitter)

    self.tab_layout = QHBoxLayout(Window.tabWidget)
    self.tab_layout.addWidget(self.splitter2)

    print "New Tab created"

  def Close(self):
    pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I do not know what happens. It does not work. What am i doing wrong? Hope you can help me

Comment: paste the code that makes your mainwindow show up?

Comment: No i mean how you instantiate your window and called `show` to make it show up not the ui file

Comment: You mean like i edited?

Comment: Yeah...your code has too many typo's and errors...please fix it and make sure it runs on your machine before posting